# Movie with missing scientists father in another dimension, worm holes in buildings

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, wormhole

I’m searching for a movie where there was a female character whose father or mother was a scientist who went missing. To get them back she had to get them the piece they invented, there were portals involved but the portals were only in certain buildings.

Comment: When did you watch that movie? Was it set in some future or in our time? Can you describe those portals?

Comment: I'm amazed that there are 6 (and counting) movies that vaguely match the description... seems as if more details (if possible) would help.

Comment: It was a subsection of The Simpsons, Treehouse of Horror VI, named Homer3.

Comment: @AJFaraday If you have an answer, the answer section is the place for it :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I'm not completely sure I do, particularly as it's not a movie, just part of a TV show playing with this trope.

Comment: @IceIceBaby - Editing someone else's question isn't the way to answer it. Unfortunately, your options here are very limited. You can't post an answer here, as the thread is closed. You can't vote to reopen the thread, as you need at least 3000 reputation for that. And you can't leave a comment here, as you need at least 50 rep for that. I can only advise you to either wait until you've earned enough rep to leave a comment, or just give up on answering this question altogether. I doubt your answer of _Contact_ (1997) is correct anyway, as it's not that strong of a match to the description.

Answer (score 11):

This sounds a little bit like the Netflix movie [Parallels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels_(film)).

Two grown up children receive a message from their dad, and eventually follow him through a series of parallel worlds via a single specific building that seemingly moves between them every 36 hours.

> The three find the building empty and covered in graffiti that describes alternate timelines and histories. Initially dismissive of the seemingly nonsensical graffiti, they discover that the building has transported them to an alternate Earth...

Answer (score 9):

A 1988 movie, **Alien from L.A.** fits this description; the protagonist (played
by Kathy Ireland) seeks her missing father, who has dropped out of our world
and is in a subterranean domain filled with... strange persons.

The father is an archaeologist, and the 'portals' are basements with
connections (very structurally unsound corridors) to the  underworld.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be the 2018 MCU film [*Ant-Man and the Wasp*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant-Man_and_the_Wasp)?

The main character is this film is Scott Lang, as played by Paul Rudd, but he works closely with Hope van Dyne, as played by Evangeline Lilly - this could be the female protagonist the OP is remembering. A large part of the story revolves around the main characters' attempts to retrieve van Dyne's mother from the Quantum Realm, which is reached via a special portal.

Parts of the story involve the shrinking and moving of an entire building, which is where Ant-Man and the Wasp perform a lot of their work.

Answer (score 4):

From your sparse description, I can think of two movies that fit. Both have a girl protagonist, a missing scientist father, and portals to other worlds.

1: The 2007 movie *[The Golden Compass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Compass_(film))*, based on Philip Pullman's 1995 [book of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Lights_(novel)) (originally titled *Northern Lights*), or possibly the current TV adaptation (BBC, HBO 2019-) *[His Dark Materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/His_Dark_Materials_(TV_series))*

In the book (and adaptations), we follow young Lyra Belaqua, who lives in an alternative version of Oxford University. Her scientist father goes missing near the North Pole, and Lyra struggles through a series of adventures to reunite with him and give him the titular golden compass, which is a powerful divination device that Lyra has a natural flair for using. The book and it sequels also features portals to other worlds, both variants of our own and some more alien ones. So here, we have the girl, the missing father scientist, portals, and a device the girl seeks to give to her father upon reunion.

2: The 2018 movie *[A Wrinkle in Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time_(2018_film))*, based in Madeline L'Engle's 1962 [book of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time), or possibly the [2003 movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time_(2003_film)) based on the book. Here is the beginning of Wikipedia's plot summary:

> Thirteen-year-old Meg Murry struggles to adjust at school, four years after the disappearance of her father Alex, a renowned astrophysicist. Meg and her gifted younger brother Charles Wallace are sent to the principal after Charles scolds a pair of gossiping teachers, and Meg retaliates against Veronica, her bullying next-door neighbor. Meg and her mother Kate discover Charles with an unusual visitor, Mrs. Whatsit, who claims that the tesseract – a method of space travel Alex was studying – is real. Meg and Charles meet her classmate Calvin O'Keefe, who joins them at the house of Mrs. Who, another strange friend of Charles who speaks only in quotations. Calvin has dinner with the Murrys, and Kate remembers Alex’s commitment to their research despite public ridicule. In the backyard, Mrs. Whatsit and Mrs. Who appear with Mrs. Which, revealing themselves as astral travelers. Explaining that they have come to help find Alex, who has transported himself across the universe, the Misses lead Meg, Calvin, and Charles through a tesseract to the distant planet Uriel.

Comment: If you have two answers, you should split them up in two answers so that the votes and acceptance can better reflect which one is the right one (if any).